# How to run .py pygame on Python 2.7?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

My lab used python 2.7 with pygame with a program and I'm trying to run it on my computer with no success. Things I've tried:

(1) Installing Python 2.7 and pygame on Windows 10. The program just crashes when I run it with IDLE.

(2) Running a virtual system with ubuntu and installing IDLE, Python 2.7, pygame, etc.

(a) If I open IDLE and open the file Output.py

(b) If I open a shell and type

```
 python /home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/Output.py
```

Then I get the following error

> python /home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/Output.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> File "/home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/Output.py", line 11, in
>    from Output2d import *
>
> File "/home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/Output2d.py", line 8, in
>    import ReadFile
>
> File "/home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/ReadFile.py", line 44, in
>    print get_mins()
>
> File "/home/frank/Dropbox/clab/Maze_2.2/ReadFile.py", line 37, in
>   get_mins handle = open(INPUT_FILE, 'r')
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/prob.txt'

The file prob.txt is present and is not corrupt so I'm really unsure what to do next to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: Why is this question tagged python-2.5? Also please post the error you get as text in the question as opposed to a link to an image.

Comment: Thanks Shuttle87 I've made the changes you asked for

Comment: This might be a relative vs absolute directory problem. Assuming the `data` directory is in the same directory as `ReadFile.py`, you could use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/prob.txt')` to get the absolute directory of ReadFile and concatenate it with `data/prob.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `pygame` issue, you are just missing some data files of the game  Maze: `Maze_2.2/data/*`

A file named `data/prob.txt`, you should find it

Comment: Thanks for responding. I went into the data folder and found the prob.txt there. It seems to be uncorrupted. 

What steps should I take next?

Comment: @FrankJohnLee replace `data/prob.txt` with this: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/prob.txt')` as mentioned MPlanchard